# Vuejs: Multiple Condition in a Class

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to highlight rows in a table if conditions are met; fine > 0 OR date due > date today

This code works fine but it is only for one(1) condition. If issue.fine > 0.

```java
<tr v-for="issue in issues" :key="issue.id" :class="{'text-danger font-weight-bold': issue.fine > 0}">
   <td>{{ issue.firstname}} {{ issue.lastname}}</td>
   <td>{{ issue.datedue }}</td>
</tr>
```

I need to have two(2) conditions;
1. issue.fine > 0  OR
2. issue.datedue > the date today

I tried this but it does not work.

```java
<tr v-for="issue in issues" :key="issue.id" :class="{'text-danger font-weight-bold': issue.fine > 0, issue.datedue > new Date()">
   <td>{{ issue.firstname}} {{ issue.lastname}}</td>
   <td>{{ issue.datedue }}</td>
</tr>
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&&`, not a comma.

```
issue.fine > 0 && issue.datedue > new Date()
```

The comma is syntactically fine, but behaviorally it returns the value of the final expression.

**EDIT**:

In response to your edit, the operator for OR is `||`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: I think && works but the new Date() is causing an error.

Comment: It says "Issues detected. The new issues panel displays information about deprecations, breaking changes and other potential problems".

Comment: I am sorry I for my post, I mean one of the condition must be meant. Either #1 OR #2. Not #1 AND #2.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple conditions which should be meta must be combined with an `&&`, not a comma.

```
<tr 
  v-for="issue in issues" 
  :key="issue.id" 
  :class="{'text-danger font-weight-bold': (issue.fine > 0 && issue.datedue && new Date())"
  >
  <td>{{ issue.firstname}} {{ issue.lastname}}</td>
  <td>{{ issue.datedue }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I am sorry I for my post, I mean one of the condition must be meant. Either #1 OR #2. Not #1 AND #2.

Thank you for your response. I tried your code but I can an error, "Issues detected. The new issues panel displays information about deprecations, breaking changes and other potential problems."

Comment: Oh in that case you should use `||` instead of `&&`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to move this logic to a computed property just for better readability and remove the clutter from the HTML code.